# Mac OS Outlook Adress Book Sync

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, address-book

I have a couple of Mac OS X High Sierra clients with microsoft outlook installed. We are using an on-premise exchange 2016 server and I am encountering some problems with the address book of said clients. While the contacts are syncing properly (all entries show up, when I compose a new e-mail and start to write in the "to" field), the address book stays empty.

I didn't find any relevant information regarding this problem online so this is my last hope. Is it even possible for the address book in outlook to show all global contacts in the company? And if so, how do I configure it to work properly?

Thanks in advance, and if I need to clear some things up or explain the problem more thoroughly, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you configured your Exchange account, Global address book will also sync to your client.

Do you mean when you open Address Book and see following window?
[image]

Can you search contacts in Address Book? This is by design that contacts will not directly show up, but you need to search in it.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the window I mean. Sadly it stays empty even when I search for contacts. Do you have any suggestions what could cause that?

Comment: Based on your situation, you may try removing and re-adding this account to see the results.

Comment: This problem affects all accounts in the domain, wether they were freshly created or existed for a couple of years. Maybe there are some access rights that need to be set correctly for the accounts to show up in this particular window on Mac OS? Like the access levels you have to set for a shared calendar? Honestly I'm just guessing at this point now.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software running on this computers? If yes, we can temporarily close them to see if it helps. As it occurs to all users, we can also use a "clean startup" to determine whether background programs are interfering with Office for Mac: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2398596/how-to-use-a-clean-startup-to-determine-whether-background-programs-ar